# MYSQL: version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference

Tags: mysql, linux

When I try to use :

```
mysqldump -u st -p st mydb > /tmp/st.sql
```

...to dump the database, the following error happens:

> mysqldump: relocation error: mysqldump: symbol _hash_init, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference

Why? and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem on debian squeeze when installing gdal1.8.0 from the experimental repository. I am really needing the correct answer on this!

Fixed it in Debian squeeze in the following way:

1. upgrade apt sources.list:

apt-get install -t unstable libmysqlclient16

When this is done, it works!